# Use MySQL variable to create a group by scoring

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, scoring

On MySQL 5.6 server I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
    `course` INT(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `course_desc` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `vote` INT(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `course_name` (`course`, `name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

With data:

```
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (100, 'Math', 'Mario', 10);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (100, 'Math', 'Giovanna', 8);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (100, 'Math', 'Federico', 8);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (100, 'Math', 'Arianna', 5);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (200, 'History', 'Mario', 9);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (200, 'History', 'Giovanna', 7);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (200, 'History', 'Patrizio', 3);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (200, 'History', 'Teresa', 10);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (300, 'Literacy', 'Giovanna', 7);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (300, 'Literacy', 'Federico', 6);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (300, 'Literacy', 'Arianna', 10);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (400, 'Science', 'Giovanni', 9);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (400, 'Science', 'Giovanna', 7);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (400, 'Science', 'Maria', 9);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (400, 'Science', 'Teresa', 0);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (400, 'Science', 'Carlo', 7);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (400, 'Science', 'Federico', 6);
INSERT INTO `student` (`course`, `course_desc`, `name`, `vote`) VALUES (500, 'Philosophy', 'Maria', 10);
```

This query:

```
SELECT 
    (@id := @id + 1) AS "ID", 
    t1.`course` AS "COURSE", 
    t1.`course_desc` AS "COURSE_DESC", 
    t1.`name` AS "NAME", 
    t1.`vote` AS "VOTE", 
    CASE 
        WHEN @prev_course = t1.`course` THEN 
            (
                CASE 
                    WHEN @prev_vote = t1.`vote` THEN @rank_count 
                    WHEN @prev_vote := t1.`vote` THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1 
                END 
            )
        WHEN @prev_course := t1.`course` THEN 
            (
                @rank_count := 1
            )
    END AS "RANK" 
FROM 
    (SELECT @id := 0) AS t0, 
    `student` AS t1, 
    (SELECT @prev_course := NULL) AS t2, 
    (SELECT @prev_vote := NULL) AS t3, 
    (SELECT @rank_count := 0) AS t4 
ORDER BY 
    t1.`course`, 
    t1.`vote` DESC;
```

produces a WRONG result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
ID  COURSE  COURSE_DESC NAME        VOTE    RANK
------------------------------------------------------------------
1   100     Math        Mario       10      1
2   100     Math        Giovanna    8       2
3   100     Math        Federico    8       2
4   100     Math        Arianna     5       3
5   200     History     Teresa      10      1
6   200     History     Mario       9       2
7   200     History     Giovanna    7       3
8   200     History     Patrizio    3       4
9   300     Literacy    Arianna     10      1
10  300     Literacy    Giovanna    7       2
11  300     Literacy    Federico    6       3
12  400     Science     Giovanni    9       1
13  400     Science     Maria       9       2
14  400     Science     Giovanna    7       3
15  400     Science     Carlo       7       3
16  400     Science     Federico    6       4
17  400     Science     Teresa      0       NULL
18  500     Philosophy  Maria       10      1
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This other query:

```
SELECT 
    (@id := @id + 1) AS "ID", 
    t1.`course` AS "COURSE", 
    t1.`course_desc` AS "COURSE_DESC", 
    t1.`name` AS "NAME", 
    t1.`vote` AS "VOTE", 
    CASE 
        WHEN @prev_course = t1.`course_desc` THEN 
            (
                CASE 
                    WHEN @prev_vote = t1.`vote` THEN @rank_count 
                    WHEN @prev_vote := t1.`vote` THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1 
                END 
            )
        WHEN @prev_course := t1.`course_desc` THEN 
            (
                @rank_count := 1
            )
    END AS "RANK" 
FROM 
    (SELECT @id := 0) AS t0, 
    `student` AS t1, 
    (SELECT @prev_course := NULL) AS t2, 
    (SELECT @prev_vote := NULL) AS t3, 
    (SELECT @rank_count := 0) AS t4 
ORDER BY 
    t1.`course`, 
    t1.`vote` DESC;
```

produces a VERY WRONG result

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
ID  COURSE  COURSE_DESC NAME        VOTE   RANK
------------------------------------------------------------------
1   100     Math        Mario       10     NULL
2   100     Math        Giovanna    8      1
3   100     Math        Federico    8      1
4   100     Math        Arianna     5      2
5   200     History     Teresa      10     3
6   200     History     Mario       9      4
7   200     History     Giovanna    7      5
8   200     History     Patrizio    3      6
9   300     Literacy    Arianna     10     7
10  300     Literacy    Giovanna    7      8
11  300     Literacy    Federico    6      9
12  400     Science     Giovanni    9      10
13  400     Science     Maria       9      10
14  400     Science     Giovanna    7      11
15  400     Science     Carlo       7      11
16  400     Science     Federico    6      12
17  400     Science     Teresa      0      NULL
18  500     Philosophy  Maria       10     13
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The goal is ranking the table from top (1) to bottom (n) depending on `vote` value.
Same vote = same rank.
Grouping by course.
I need some help
Tks a lot

MR

Comment: So, what's the correct result?

Comment: I need a corret rank 1, 2,3,etc depends on vote value, group per course or course desc.

Comment: <pre>ID  COURSE  COURSE_DESC NAME        VOTE    RANK
12  400 Science     Giovanni    9   1
13  400 Science     Maria        9   2

AND 

17  400 Science     Teresa      0   NULL

Are wrong</pre>

Comment: You should edit your post and describe as clearly as possible the actual ranking algorithm. Comments are not a suitable place to put functional requirements of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear on what you want.  But your use of variables is wrong.  You should not assign a variable in one expression and then refer to it in another.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`, so they might be evaluated in the wrong order.

I think you want something like this:

```
select s.*,
       (@rn := if(@c = course_desc, @rn + 1,
                  if(@c := course_desc, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rank
from (select s.*
      from student s
      order by s.course_desc, s.vote desc
     ) s cross join
     (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params;
```

If you want students with the same vote to have the same value:

```
select s.*,
       (@rn := if(@cv = concat_ws(':', course_desc, vote), @rn,
                  if(@cv like concat(course_desc, ':%'),
                     if(@cv := concat_ws(':', course_desc, vote), @rn + 1, @rn + 1),
                     if(@cv := concat_ws(':', course_desc, vote), 1, 1)
                    )
                 )
       ) as rank
from (select s.*
      from student s
      order by s.course_desc, s.vote desc
     ) s cross join
     (select @cv := '', @rn := 0) params
```

Comment: @user9846973 . . . Take some time to understand the logic.  You can break apart the different parts of the `if()` to see what is happening.  This is a really powerful construct . . . of course, when you upgrade to MySQL 8.0, you won't need it any more because window functions pretty much replace the use of variables in many situations.

Comment: @user9846973 you might want to reward this answer by accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using `LEFT JOIN` instead of variables:

```
SELECT s1.course, s1.course_desc, s1.name, s1.vote, COUNT(s2.name) + 1 AS rank
FROM student AS s1
LEFT JOIN student AS s2 
   ON s1.course = s2.course AND s1.name <> s2.name AND s1.vote < s2.vote
GROUP BY s1.course, s1.course_desc, s1.name, s1.vote  
ORDER BY s1.course, rank
```

The query assumes each student is uniquely identified by his/her name. In a real-world scenario you would substitute the name with an id.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce5cd7/4)